# How to Run selenium automation test cases on some web application using my own testing web application

Tags: c#, selenium, model-view-controller, selenium-chromedriver

I made selenium automation framework to test a web application and Now I am trying to Run my test cases using a simple web application where I can Run my test cases anywhere.

I made MVC web application and I could run it on local host but when I published my web application to server I couldn't use chromeDriver.exe file .

On local host I use it this way:

```
WebDriver driver = new ("path of chromeDriver.exe")
```

Is there any way to pass this problem even using another driver or some way to have a copy of `chromeDriver.exe` on my server and use it

Comment: Provide some more information what you have tried?

Comment: Where are you hosting your app? Some servers does not allow web app to run exe files. Others required you to enable it first.

Comment: You need to place your chromeDriver.exe on the server on the exact path you hardcoded in your app or make the executable path configurable via configuration file and specify driver's exe path from your server.

Comment: I placed chromeDriver.exe in the server host PC and gave the path of it in my code but it doesn't work .. can I include it some way in my project or do some thing so that I can use it from server